# facebook app, submiting and using of same app in several pages

Tags: facebook

i have an app that i want to submit so i will be able to use in a client page/business profile. i need 5 total users and for some reason that people that open the app didn't count in for the total users.... is there something needed to be done in order for them to count.

second question is... if i will have an app for a specific page, is it possible (and how?) to have that same page do different thing with a variable in the query for each client tab we will have in the feature?

Update:

I don't want users - i want to use the app in the page tabs!
by "that people that open the app didnot count in for total users" i mean that the total user count is not going up

Comment: you are not clear with your question. First what kind of users do you want? what do you mean by "that people that open the app didnot count in for total users"?

Comment: code for what? it is an iframe for a page on our server. for some reason that app of the iframe doesn't request permission for use and does not added to my apps